# Should you upgrade to ubuntu 20.04LTS from ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: upgrade, versions

I'm considering upgrading to lastest LTS even though my LTS version works fine. Wondering if those security patches are worth the upgrade.

Comment: 18.04 gets the same security patches as other releases of Ubuntu. 18.04 and 20.04 are equally *safe*. One is merely newer. The official, tested upgrade path opens when 20.04.1 is released in about three months.

Comment: You may very well get better results with the newer LTS, but the contrary may be even more probable. The much newer kernel may fix problems if you have them. If you don't have them you should stay with the old one. If you want to test the new LTS try it in a new partition, in multiboot.

Comment: I want to upgrade because the new GNOME shell version is supposedly much more stable and feature rich.

Comment: I personally suggest (not an expert at all) to wait even a bit more. Upgraded less than a month ago and had problems with sound, wifi, few indefinite freezes, and had minor mouse click issues. Of course, that might be quite specific to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just upgraded and I would suggest to wait for another month. There are some repositories that do not have 20.04 support yet (e.g. TeXLive, MikTex). And I also noticed that Nautilus doesn't feel 100% smooth as before (e.g. it crashed on me, when I ctrl + c a file inside and archive).

As others wrote, the security is not significantly better, so wait if you can.

Comment: This depends on the repos that you have setup. Nautilus seems to work fine for me. Don't know what the problem there is

Answer (score 2):

yes! you should upgrade to latest version , because it is much smoother and better. UI is decent and kernel 5.4 causes faster boots. But here take a note....in my case i upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS , and now i am experiencing UI glitches...and some lags...so my straightforward suggestion would be to have a clean install!

Comment: See up is not the problem for me since I have custome gnome look (macos look) . I see but i don't want to loose all the programs and stuff

Comment: I would like to ask a relevant question. I have a virtual box with Ubuntu 18.04LTS installed. If I upgrade to 20.04LTS will I lose all of my programs? I am afraid that some of them may crash due to updated dependencies. Is this true? For example I installed Jenkins. Will I have to re-install it?